# Is there an easy way for someone completely naive to docker and web hosting to set up connectivity to their website?

Tags: django, docker

I am very new to the whole development thing so I apologize for the simpleness of my question. I have been scouring the internet and reading articles and watching videos trying to to this docker/django combo I have going live. Everything I've looked at seems to be intended for people who know somewhat what they are doing. It's just not clicking for me reading the documentation and reading these articles. The leap to actually launching this kind of software is what's getting me. I tried AWS, DockerHub, and a few others.

My goal is just to get this little Django app I have going so that I can connect to it from work in the web browser without having my laptop there. I want my coworkers to be able to use it as they are a bit technically illiterate and it really simplifies this one thing that they have to do semi-daily.

I hope this is enough pertinent info, but let me know if not. I have two separate docker images. One for MariaDB and the other for Django.

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"

# container networks to set up
networks:
  django_db_net:
    external: false

# the containers to spin up
services:
  django:
    build: ./docker/django
    restart: 'unless-stopped'
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - django_db_net
    user: "${HOST_USER_ID}:${HOST_GROUP_ID}"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
    working_dir: /src/chopper
    command: ["/src/wait-for-it.sh", "db:3306", "--", "python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
#    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "${DJANGO_PORT}:8000"

  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    user: "${HOST_USER_ID}:${HOST_GROUP_ID}"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=this_is_a_bad_password
      - MYSQL_USER=django
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=django
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=chopper
    networks:
      - django_db_net
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM python:latest
# update pip
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip & \
  pip3 install django mysqlclient relatorio
ENV MYSQL_MAJOR 8.0
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 8C718D3B5072E1F5 & \
  echo "deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ buster mysql-${MYSQL_MAJOR}" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list & apt-get update & \
  apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install default-libmysqlclient-dev
WORKDIR /src
```

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand from your question is that you want to deploy a webservice that can be accessed publicly using python/django and docker.

My recomendation is to check out Heroku.
https://www.heroku.com/continuous-integration
specifically
https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker

And maybe integrate it with Github or GitLab.

As far as I remember Heroku provides you with free deployment to host your service for free ( with some limitations of course ) but it would be a perfect fit for your ask.